# In implements method, addmarker do not work / GoogleMap, Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

**CODE**

```
public class BlueFragment2 extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blue, container, false);
        MapView mapview = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map_blue);
        mapview.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapview.onResume();
        mapview.getMapAsync(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
        LatLng point = new LatLng(googleMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude(), googleMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(point).title("ok");
        googleMap.clear();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(point, 14));
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I wanted that OnMyLocationButton click will addmarker on the google map.

But it doesn't work.

If i wrote on `public void onMapReady` like

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    googleMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
            LatLng point = new LatLng(googleMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude(), googleMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude());
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(point).title("ok");
            googleMap.clear();
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(point, 14));
            googleMap.addMarker(marker);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

It works well.

Why this do not work?

Would you help me?

**Question :**

Is there any other way except writing on `public void onMapReady`?

Is there my fault in using `implements googleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener`?

Comment: @Jai , Because if i use in onMapReady setting my location (android's my location:http://uploads.tapatalk-cdn.com/20140613/6ebeqyzy.jpg) disabled, there happened error when i click onMyLocationButton.

Comment: Set `googleMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this)` inside onMapReady() if you want implement by class and use your first method.

Comment: marker add when your lat log is not null you just need latlog